# How to include non-pip dependencies in AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: python, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to deploy a Flask app on Elastic Beanstalk, however I get the following error when I run `eb create`:

```
ERROR: Your requirements.txt is invalid. Snapshot your logs for details.
ERROR: [Instance: i-04837a6167d3738a3] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: (TRUNCATED)...)
   File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 541, in check_call
     raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
CalledProcessError: Command '/opt/python/run/venv/bin/pip install -r /opt/python/ondeck/app/requirements.txt' returned non-zero exit status 1. 
Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03deploy.py failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

It seems the problem is coming from an article extraction library that the app uses (http://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) which has some dependencies such as `sudo apt-get install libxml2-dev libxslt-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libjpeg-dev zlib1g-dev libpng12-dev`.

How can I install these dependencies on Elastic Beanstalk?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a couple options.

You can install all of the required packages and then create an image of the server with your packages installed.   You can then use that AMI when you launch any new instances and those packages will be available.

You can also manage it in code, by using .ebextensions.   You can use this to install any packages you need when the server boots up.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html

An example of how this can work is where I replace apache with nginx for a beanstalk application:  https://github.com/ricktbaker/beanstalk-nginx-php-fpm

Or you can create a custom platform.  This might be a little overkill for you needs, but it is an option:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/custom-platforms.html